# Using 'only' directive with AND condition

Tags: gitlab-ci

How do I run a job only when say, its a branch, AND tagged? Something like

```
only
    - branches
    - /^staging-/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a **branch** called **feature-1** and your question is how do I match **only tags that are called staging-*** this is your only block:

```
only
  - tags
  - /^staging-/
```

If you want to target only tags based on certain branches that seems not possible at this time. Only when you have a naming convention like above. Since Gitlab cannot determine what branch a certain tag was based on.

Comment: No. Say, I have a feature branch called new_feature, and I want job to run only if it is git tagged with a staging-<some text>

Comment: Improved the answer based on comment.

Comment: It's my guess too that this is not possible. If I'm not mistaken, your `only` block means run job for *any* tags OR if refspec matches staging-*